# Issues in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

How to Display The List View Individual Item Names as Individual Layout Header Names?
HERE IS MY CODE:In this code only My app name  Displays as a title to all layouts.but I want Individual list of item names as a header Names in Individual layout?

```
ListView list;

int i;
String[] places = {"AP State Archaeology Museum","Birla Mandir","Birla Planetarium","Charminar","Chowmahalla Palace",
        "Golkonda Fort", "Hussain Sagar","Lumbini Park","Makkah Masjid","Mrugavani National Park","Nehru Zoological Park","Nizam Museum",
        "Ramoji Film City", "Salar Jung Museum","Shilparamam"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.places);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,places);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Apstate.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if (position == 1)
            {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Birla.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
            if (position == 2)
            {
                Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BirlaPlanetarium.class);
                startActivity(i2);
            }
            if (position == 3)
            {
                Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Charminar.class);
                startActivity(i3);
            }
            if (position == 4)
            {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Chowmahal.class);
                startActivity(i4);
            }
            if (position == 5)
            {
                Intent i5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Golkonda.class);
                startActivity(i5);
            }
            if (position == 6)
            {
                Intent i6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hussiansagar.class);
                startActivity(i6);
            }
            if (position == 7)
            {
                Intent i7 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Lumbinipark.class);
                startActivity(i7);
            }
            if (position == 8)
            {
                Intent i8 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Meccamasjid.class);
                startActivity(i8);
            }
            if (position == 9)
            {
                Intent i9 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Mrugavani.class);
                startActivity(i9);
            }
            if (position == 10)
            {
                Intent i10 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Nehrupark.class);
                startActivity(i10);
            }
            if (position == 11)
            {
                Intent i11 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Nizam.class);
                startActivity(i11);
            }
            if (position == 12)
            {
                Intent i12 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ramoji.class);
                startActivity(i12);
            }
            if (position == 13)
            {
                Intent i13 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Salarjung.class);
                startActivity(i13);
            }
            if (position == 14)
            {
                Intent i14 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,shilparamam.class);

                startActivity(i14);
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Use `putExtra` with `Intent` on `Listview Item Click` with using `Position`.

Comment: Can you please add your code whatever you have tried?

Comment: Please tell me one thing, is all class (Ramoji, Salarjung, etc) have same layout(contents i.e. TextView, EditText) or different layout? If there is no different layouts, I suggest you to use only one class and do operation based on passed string intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First U should get the String of listview on click and then pass the string to another activity by using put extra and its obj name

As per urs u should do something lik this,

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String value=list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Apstate.class);
                    i.putExtra("ListView_value",value);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Birla.class);
                    i1.putExtra("ListView_value",value);
                    startActivity(i1);
                }
                ....// same like the above do for all
                ...
                ...
            }

        });
```

then ur activity class be like :

```
    Apstate Class Activtiy:-

String value;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
value = extras.getString("ListView_value");
setTitle(value);
```

Birla Class Activtiy:-

```
String value;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
value = extras.getString("ListView_value");
setTitle(value);
```

Should do for all other classes...

```
    same like that in all class activity class
    ......
```

Comment: actually i m using implicit list view in android.android.R.layout.simple_drop down_item_line, i m not creating any custom list view.then how to solve?

Comment: For faster process, you can use switch case instead of if condition.

Comment: can u explain the ap state class activity.y we are using Bundle extras

Comment: Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all the primitive types , Parcelables, Serializables. Since we used putExtra we used .getExtras(); for getting the values passed on that activity

Comment: how to add map to the ap state activity and that map must be shown in  same activity it will not go to maps @Learner actually i m writing like this                                                                                                     public void displayMap(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:17.3990003,78.4676841?q=Ap Stae Museum"));
        i.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(i);
    } it will goes to maps app but i want this is in same activity then how?

Comment: I think ur work is going deeper,so My guess ur trying to open a map fragment in that activity with a marker postion and if user click other list mean ur opening some other activity and showing position of that place ?

Comment: According to ur work progress, u should work on the Maps first, so that only able to open map fragment in same activity..

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/google-maps/android-google-maps-v2-tutorial/ learn from this tutorial. ur progress is big so first u have to work on maps and then do ur stuff

Comment: k thanks for u r suggestion.i have one problem hear i am applying scroll view to text content in ap state activity and i m adjusting one image at the top of text content.now i m applying scroll view to image view and textview but it shows error "unfortunately stopped" when i click on ap state item?how to solve ?My requirement is image is also scrolled with text content in activity

Comment: U may ask this question in separate and place a piece of code of tht activity with logcat. dude. give here ur link i try my best

Comment: finally i get it dude.thnks

Answer (score 0):

- you are listed all data within ArrayList
- Pass position of ArrayList or pass entire arraylist through putExtra with Intent on Listview Item Click.